# How to create LDAP users in bulk on Linux (UBUNTU)

Tags: server, ldap, openldap

i just install LDAP server on my server and its working fine. now i would like to create 20 users with different names so is there any script to create users in bulk on LDAP server.

OS: ubuntu 20.04 server

Comment: See the explanation (with example) [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ldap) under "Modifying and populating your database". In short: create a text file with the data on the 20 users, and use the `ldapadd` command to process it.

Comment: @Jos that reads like an answer ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind That may be so but I can't think why the OP didn't come up with it themselves. It is literally the starting page about the OpenLDAP server.

Comment: Manual answers are easy rep :=) @Jos

Answer (score 1):

On the [page that describes the OpenLDAP server](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ldap), there are a couple of examples of how to add groups and users.

Keep in mind that:

- before you can add a user to a group, the group must be defined
- before you can add a group, there must be an *ou* (organizational unit) defined to store groups. Let's call this `Groups`.
- before you can add a user, there must be an *ou* to store people in; call this `People`.

The aforementioned page (under "Modifying and populating your database") gives examples of all these. The basic steps are:

- create a text file defining all of the above;
- use the `ldapadd` command to process this text file.